# Extending script execution time beyond 5 minutes for reddit scraping

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm attempting to gather all of the posts submitted to a particular subreddit using the code found here: https://www.labnol.org/internet/web-scraping-reddit/28369/  However the execution limit is reached well before this completes.

I am looking for a way to extend the run time of the script, with it ideally not needing my intervention at all once I click run.

```
const getThumbnailLink_ = url => {
  if (!/^http/.test(url)) return '';
  return `=IMAGE("${url}")`;
};

const getHyperlink_ = (url, text) => {
  if (!/^http/.test(url)) return '';
  return `=HYPERLINK("${url}", "${text}")`;
};

const writeDataToSheets_ = data => {
  const values = data.map(r => [
    new Date(r.created_utc * 1000),
    r.title,
    getThumbnailLink_(r.thumbnail),
    getHyperlink_(r.url, 'Link'),
    getHyperlink_(r.full_link, 'Comments')
  ]);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};

const isRateLimited_ = () => {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.pushshift.io/meta');
  const { server_ratelimit_per_minute: limit } = JSON.parse(response);
  return limit < 1;
};

const getAPIEndpoint_ = (subreddit, before = '') => {
  const fields = ['title', 'created_utc', 'url', 'thumbnail', 'full_link'];
  const size = 10000;
  const base = 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission';
  const params = { subreddit, size, fields: fields.join(',') };
  if (before) params.before = before;
  const query = Object.keys(params)
    .map(key => `${key}=${params[key]}`)
    .join('&');
  return `${base}?${query}`;
};

const scrapeReddit = (subreddit = 'AskMen') => {
  let before = '';
  do {
    const apiUrl = getAPIEndpoint_(subreddit, before);
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiUrl);
    const { data } = JSON.parse(response);
    const { length } = data;
    before = length > 0 ? String(data[length - 1].created_utc) : '';
    if (length > 0) {
      writeDataToSheets_(data);
    }
  } while (before !== '' && !isRateLimited_());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's a better practice to optimize your script to not reach the execution time defined by your quota. So in your case, one solution is to reduce the batch size per execution. In the reference you linked the code fetches 1000 posts per batch, your code fetches 10000.

Try with smaller values to see if the script execution time does not exceed quota anymore.

```
const getAPIEndpoint_ = (subreddit, before = '') => {
  const fields = ['title', 'created_utc', 'url', 'thumbnail', 'full_link'];
  const size = 1000;
  const base = 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission';
  const params = { subreddit, size, fields: fields.join(',') };
  if (before) params.before = before;
  const query = Object.keys(params)
    .map(key => `${key}=${params[key]}`)
    .join('&');
  return `${base}?${query}`;
};
```

But if you have a business need to exceed your quota, you can upgrade to to either `Google Workspace Basic, Business or Enterprise` - depending on how much you need to increase your quota and how much you are willing to pay.

See [here](https://workspace.google.com/pricing.html) for more information about different accounts and pricing.